# How to install POP3 server on W10?

Tags: windows-10, pop3

I'm trying to install POP3 mail server on W10.
According to what I've found on the web I should be able to install it
as an added feature please see below.
Even when I expanded all sections I couldn't find it anywhere.

[image]

Where it supposed to be located ?

Any guidance much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may be looking for a feature that is included in a different version of windows. For example, Windows Server 2016 has the [SMTP Server Feature](https://www.znetlive.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2016/10/8-SMTP-e1519034755366.jpg). However, your version of Windows **might not include it.**

In your case it may be best to use a thrid-party utility, such as [hMailServer](https://www.hmailserver.com/download), in order to run your own mail server. I have also included a guide to setting up hMailServer below, but setting up your own **server** is different from setting up your own mail **client**.

(If you are trying to access an email account you already have, you may just need a client. Please see below.)

## hMailServer Guide

[Setup Your Own Simple SMTP Server — How To (medium.com)](https://medium.com/@coffmans/setup-your-own-simple-smtp-server-how-to-c9159cfc7934)

## Server Environment

Unless it is for testing or internal LAN use, an email server will usually have a fully qualified domain name, and reside on a server with a commercial/corporate internet connection. **Residential ISPs typically have rules against running your own mail server.** You may also need to have reverse dns records and implement DKIM signing.
If you do not have these you might not be able to send or receive emails.

## Email Client

If you already have an email address and are looking to access your email, you can use the built in [Windows Mail App [Guide]](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/set-up-email-in-the-mail-app-for-windows-10-7ff79e8b-439b-4b47-8ff9-3f9a33166c60).

Answer (score 2):

Windows does not feature an email server.

Microsoft's product for doing that is
[Microsoft Exchange Server](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Exchange_Server),
which is payware and quite complicated to manage.

Free email servers do exists, such as
[Baby POP3 Server](http://www.pablosoftwaresolutions.nl/html/baby_pop3_server.html).
See also the article
[What is the best free mail server for Windows 10](https://windowsreport.com/free-mail-server-windows-10/).
(I don't have a personal recommendation.)